# What are the equation that gives hurst exponent of value >0.7 and <0.3?

Tags: matlab, hurst-exponent

I had been working on algorithm which uses the Hurst Exponent. Once i random walk simulation on matlab, x = cumsum(randm(1000,1)), I was able to get a hurst value close to 0.5.

To analyze the use of Hurst Exponent in mean aversion or mean reversion, may i know what are the equation models that i can used to run Monte Carlo simulations?

Answer (score 4):

The corresponding process would be 
*fractional brownian motion* (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Brownian_motion))

It is parametrized by the Hurst Exponent.

On the referenced site you find a link to some matlab code for simulating realizations of fractional BM.

If you want to see some fractional Gaussian Noise in action (Matlab) you can do so
[here](http://www.symmys.com/node/131).

Further more you might want to look into ARFIMA processes...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was thinking more of a simulated equation, ARMA model that gives a hurst exponent of 0.7 and above, and another ARMA model that gives a hurst exponent of 0.3 and lower. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I edited my answer.